# Factory Reset Asus

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, factory-defaults

I have an ASUS All-in-one PC (not sure what model) and I'm trying to perform a Factory Restore but nothing is working yet.

I have tried pressing F8, all I had access to was "Restore from an earlier point" - Today was the earliest point; and "Restore from an Image" - which I don't have.

I have tried pressing F9, F10, and F11, but all that brought me was options to Start Windows normally, Run a system diagnostic, or try other options (F8 menu).

I don't have any other discs to restore from or anything, and I have found a tutorial to try and create a Partition(?) to load the restore from that.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just install Windows 7 yourself?  Your license key is printed on a label on the computer.  There is a question on this very website that explains where to get Windows 7 ISOs from Microsoft's digital partner

Comment: @Ramhound can you please link the question for me?

Comment: I cannot do that.  If you spend 5 minutes looking for it you will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, you will have better luck just re-installing Windows 7

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d

The above link provide the official downloadable .iso of the various Windows OS.

The product key can be found on the product key stick on your PC.

Burn the iso to a disc, insert, boot from the the disc, follow the onscreen instructions and sorted.